# .NET & AngularJS slow response times on Appharbor

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, performance, appharbor

On Appharbor the response time for our activity logs are over 2 minutes at some points and sometimes 30 seconds just to login. We are using a service to ping the server to keep it up and running but with minimal effect.

Here is the repository:
https://github.com/343-Epoch/epoch-trackr

Are we doing something AppHarbor doesn't like? The responses are slow on local but more in the range of a couple seconds. Also, firefox and internet explorer will occasionally load faster which doesn't make sense to me.

Here are the links to two different instances running on AppHarbor, one with just one build and one with all of our builds. We have separate ones because earlier AppHarbor was injecting code from previous builds into the latest somehow (it was random and not for every instance). We still have no clue how that was happening and just made the new instance.

epoch-trackr.apphb.com
epoch-trackr-prod.apphb.com